# Certbot-auto --manual plugin not working

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, lets-encrypt, certbot

I already generated certificates using certbot-auto with --manual plugin. Now the certbot version upgraded from 0.25.1 to 0.26.1, now i’m not able to use the --manual option as it says deprecated in the certbot 0.26.1.

This is the command i used to generate the certificate -

```
`./certbot-auto certonly --manual -d *.example.com -d example.com --preferred-challenges dns-01 --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory`
```

Is there any other related plugin like --manual? where i can generate the TXT record and update it in my aws route53.

Comment: The manual plugin doesn't seem to be deprecated in the last version, could you post the error you are getting when running that command?

Comment: Requesting to rerun ./certbot-auto with root privileges...
Error: couldn't get currently installed version for /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt: 
/var/www/ does not exist or is not a directory

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Certbot Route53 Plugin](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/tree/master/certbot-dns-route53)

From the documentation:

- > ```
  > certbot certonly \   
  > -n --agree-tos --email DEVOPS@COMPANY.COM \  
  > --dns-route53 \
  > -d MY.DOMAIN.NAME
  > ```